# GULP SASS requiring multiple paths

Tags: sass, gulp, include-path

how can i include multiple required paths using gulp-sass. it works fine with just one path like:

```
   .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: require('node-normalize-scss').includePaths,
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
```

i’ve already tried passing those paths in an array. but it doesn't work neither.

```
    var neat = require('node-neat').includePaths,
        normalize = require('node-normalize-scss').includePaths;

   .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [
              normalize,
              neat
        ],
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the `includePaths` property could return an array, try the following syntax :

```
sass({
    includePaths: [].concat(normalize, neat),
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
})
```